# I can handle two different elements in an xml type?

Tags: java, xml

For example I have this:

```
@XmlType( propOrder = { "ChiaveCondizione", "ChiaveCondizione_Versione", "ElencoPreventivi"} )
public class StrOutput
{
    @XmlElement( name = "ChiaveCondizione", targetType=java.lang.String.class, cardinality = Cardinality.ONE )
    private java.lang.String ChiaveCondizione;

    @XmlElement( name = "ChiaveCondizione_Versione", targetType=java.lang.String.class, cardinality = Cardinality.ONE )
    private java.lang.String ChiaveCondizione_Versione;

    @XmlElement( name = "ElencoPreventivi", targetType=ArrayOfStrPreventivo.class, cardinality = Cardinality.ONE )
    private ArrayOfStrPreventivo ElencoPreventivi;


    public void setChiaveCondizione(java.lang.String ChiaveCondizione)
    {
        this.ChiaveCondizione = ChiaveCondizione;
    }

    public java.lang.String getChiaveCondizione()
    {
        return ChiaveCondizione;
    }

    public void setChiaveCondizione_Versione(java.lang.String ChiaveCondizione_Versione)
    {
        this.ChiaveCondizione_Versione = ChiaveCondizione_Versione;
    }

    public java.lang.String getChiaveCondizione_Versione()
    {
        return ChiaveCondizione_Versione;
    }

    public void setElencoPreventivi(ArrayOfStrPreventivo ElencoPreventivi)
{
    this.ElencoPreventivi = ElencoPreventivi;
}

    public ArrayOfStrPreventivo getElencoPreventivi()
    {
        return ElencoPreventivi;
    }
}
```

but I need to manage ElencoPreventivi according to two different structures based on the code calls
The two structures are these:

1.

```
@XmlType( propOrder = { "strPrev"} )
public class ArrayOfStrPrev
{
    @XmlElement( name = "strPrev", targetType=StrPreventivo.class, cardinality = Cardinality.MANY )
private java.util.List<StrPreventivo> strPreventivo = new java.util.ArrayList<StrPreventivo>();

public void setStrPreventivo(java.util.List<StrPreventivo> strPreventivo)
{
    this.strPreventivo = strPreventivo;
}

public java.util.List<StrPreventivo> getStrPreventivo()
{
    return strPreventivo;
}

}
```

2.

```
    @XmlType( propOrder = { "strPreventivo"} )
public class ArrayOfStrPreventivo
{
    @XmlElement( name = "strPreventivo", targetType=StrPreventivo.class, cardinality = Cardinality.MANY )
    private java.util.List<StrPreventivo> strPreventivo = new java.util.ArrayList<StrPreventivo>();

    public void setStrPreventivo(java.util.List<StrPreventivo> strPreventivo)
    {
        this.strPreventivo = strPreventivo;
    }

    public java.util.List<StrPreventivo> getStrPreventivo()
    {
        return strPreventivo;
    }

}
```

It's possible to do this? maybe adding something or running it from the property?
It's possible a cast?

I have to get results of some type and others of another type, but in the end the structure must be similar.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess

you can use Object class instead (which is correponds to `xsd:any` type) of `ArrayOfStrPreventivo` at

```
@XmlElement( name = "ElencoPreventivi", targetType=Object.class, cardinality = Cardinality.ONE )
private Object elencoPreventivi;
```

Of course you have to check and make casting when you will use it.
Or (as long as you are going with bottom-up approach) you can have other separate not-annotated Getters/Setters  like

```
public ArrayOfStrPreventivo getElencoPreventivi1() {
    if (elencoPreventivi instanceof ArrayOfStrPreventivo){
     return elencoPreventivi;
    } else {
     return null;
}

public ArrayOfStrPrev getElencoPreventivi2() {
    if (elencoPreventivi instanceof ArrayOfStrPrev){
     return elencoPreventivi;
    } else {
     return null;
}
```

or delegate it to the caller by using generic

```
public <T> T getElencoPreventivi() {
     return (T)elencoPreventivi;
}
```

It is also possible to use a `choice` - but for that you have to have different XMLElements for `ArrayOfStrPrev` and `ArrayOfStrPreventivo` in XML and anyway it ends-up with `List<Object>` - so casting still required:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "arrayOfStrPrev", type = ArrayOfStrPrev.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "arrayOfStrPreventivo", type = ArrayOfStrPreventivo.class)
})
protected List<Object> arrayOfStrPrevOrarrayOfStrPreventivo;
```

For that XML will look like:

```
<strOutput>
    ...
    <arrayOfStrPrev>
          <strPrev>
             ...
          </strPrev>
          <strPrev>
             ...
          </strPrev>
             ...
    </arrayOfStrPrev>
</strOutput>
```

or

```
<strOutput>
    ...
    <arrayOfStrPreventivo>
          <strPreventivo>
             ...
          </strPreventivo>
          <strPreventivo>
             ...
          </strPreventivo>
             ...
    </arrayOfStrPreventivo>
</strOutput>
```

UPDATED: test XSD schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/test"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/test" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <element name="strOutputAnyType" type="tns:StrOutputAnyType" />

  <element name="strOutputChoice" type="tns:StrOutputChoice" />

  <complexType name="StrOutputAnyType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="ElencoPreventivi" type="anyType" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="StrOutputChoice">
    <sequence>
        <choice>
            <element name="arrayOfStrPrev" type="tns:ArrayOfStrPrev" />
            <element name="arrayOfStrPreventivo" type="tns:ArrayOfStrPreventivo" />
        </choice>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="ArrayOfStrPrev">
    <sequence>
        <element name="strPrev" type="tns:StrPrev" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="ArrayOfStrPreventivo">
    <sequence>
        <element name="StrPreventivo" type="tns:StrPreventivo"
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <simpleType name="StrPrev">
    <restriction base="string" />
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="StrPreventivo">
    <restriction base="string" />
  </simpleType>

</schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions Vadim, but in your first solution I'm breaking up here on setElencoPreventivi(prev):
'
ArrayOfStrPreventivo prev = new ArrayOfStrPreventivo();
                            ArrayList<StrPreventivo> list = new ArrayList<StrPreventivo>(1);
                            list.add(CalcoloPreventivoIO.outputPreventivo);
                            prev.setStrPreventivo(list);
                            localOutput.setElencoPreventivi(prev);
'

where 
public void setElencoPreventivi(Object ElencoPreventivi)
    {
  
   this.ElencoPreventivi = ElencoPreventivi;
  
 }

Comment: While your second solution does not allow me:
It does not accept @XmlElements and wants cardinality as a parameter

Comment: For first one what problem at what point do you have? for the second from what package and what version do you use @XmlElement annotation? My example for standard JDK 1.7 - 1.8 JAXB `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement`  which does not have `cardinality` and there is `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElements`. It seems like you use something else...

Comment: In the first solution I'm breaking up here on setElencoPreventivi(prev).

Comment: I use fr.norsys.asoape.xml.soap

Comment: Sorry, never heard of it. Still from XML prospective you have those two choices. Maybe you need to find out how your framework handles them... If it has ability to generate code for up-down approach, try to do with the XSD from my UPDATED answer and see what classes and annotations where generated.